# Angular2, Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Tags: angular

The imports:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Application } from './Application';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

The Method:

```
 saveApplcation() {
    var application = new Application();
    application.ssnr = this.form.value.ssnr;
    application.loanamount = this.form.value.amount;
    application.email = this.form.value.email;
    application.phonenumber = this.form.value.phonenumber;
    application.repaymenttime = this.form.value.time;

    var body: string = JSON.stringify(application);
    var headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });

    this._http.post("api/Application/", body, { headers: headers })
        .map(returnData => returnData.toString())
        .subscribe(
        retur => {
            this.showForm = false;
            this.showMenu = true;
        },
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("done post-api/loan")
        );

};
```

The error says: TS2339  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.   TypeScript Virtual Projects C:\Users\kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NewOblig3\NewOblig3\app\app.component.ts 52  Active

I've seen People import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; and says it'll work, but not in my case.

Comment: Looks like you have written wrong:  retur => {. Change it to return

Comment: retur is just a variable i think. Don't think it affects the error though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Visual Studio. I had the same issue there.

I solved it by installing 
[TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

It also fixed IntelliSense for Observable.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem after upgrading from an earlier beta.  My issue (and I suspect yours) was in the configuration files package.json and systemjs.config.js.  Honestly, I'm not 100% sure what the exact lines that fixed the problem but the format of systemjs.config.js in particular is quite different.

My recommended solution is use these two configuration files from the [Quick Start Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to replace your own then run `npm install`.

After I updated these, I did not need the `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` fix; everything worked correctly.

Note: You should backup these files before making these changes to make sure you don't lose customizations, and there will probably other issues caused by the upgrades.